# blazor oauth AuthenticationService.js:2 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'

Tags: oauth-2.0, blazor, content-security-policy

//I known that there are some topics about that but non that i found use blazor. - i didnt found any helping mi out one.

Im using oauth in my blazor app
I created login component as in
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

and configured it

and it works fine. redirrect to login page, then i can login , then redirrect me to my app again
using RedirectToLoginComponent as in MS help website
and then after login - login component is stuck at

```
 Authentication
 Completing login...
```

and in console i see

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://xx.corpnet.pl') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://xx.localhost').

how to configure it ? i tried in `<meta>` tak but frame ancestors are not allowed

i tryed also in server project

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
 {
  context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy",  "frame-ancestors, 'self' https://xx.corpnet.pl " );
  await next();
 });
```

what am i missing here? how to configure that for blazor wasm ?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for blazur client to add this we have to do this this way:

```
var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
 OnPrepareResponse = context =>
 {
    context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self' https://xx.corpnet.pl;frame-src 'self' https://yy.corpnet.pl;");
}
};

 app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html",staticFileOptions);
```